# Unable to build piggybank -> /home/build/ivy/lib does not exist

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

hey all I followed the steps here: http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PiggyBank
to build the piggybank jar but I keep getting the output below. I also built the pig project from source and reference that in my .bash_profile:

```
    cloudera@cloudera-demo:~/piggybank/java$ ./makepiggy.sh 
Buildfile: /home/cloudera/piggybank/java/build.xml

download-hive-deps:

init:

compile:
     [echo]  *** Compiling Pig UDFs ***
    [javac] /home/cloudera/piggybank/java/build.xml:100: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 153 source files to /home/cloudera/piggybank/java/build/classes

BUILD FAILED
/home/cloudera/piggybank/java/build.xml:100: /home/build/ivy/lib does not exist.
```

here is my bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/cloudera/pig/trunk/pig.jar
```

** UPDATE **
The docs were incorrect on the Wiki page, they appear to be correct now: http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PiggyBank

follow the new instructions and you should be fine

Comment: I was having the same problem, so I created this dir: /home/build/ivy/lib, and after this i'm still stuck.

Answer (score 3):

The docs were incorrect on the Wiki page, they appear to be correct now: http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PiggyBank

follow the new instructions and you should be fine

Create a directory for the Pig source code: mkdir pig

cd into that directory: cd pig

Checkout the Pig source code: svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/ .

Build the project: ant

cd into the piggybank dir: cd contrib/piggybank/java

Build the piggybank: ant
You should now see a piggybank.jar file in that directory.

Comment: I'm using the HD Insight local server, and got caught out because it's missing the "build" folder - even though you've already got Pig as part of the install, you'll need to get the fresh code from SVN and rebuild. Not hard though